# Looking for a word that defines both size and position

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing an application and can not figure out a proper abstract term that would fit an interface that defines an object as Movable and Resizable (In essence, something that has a defined size and defined position).

Calling it Movable and resizable is kind of silly.
Layout was a term that came to my mind but it is not good as layout is something that is responsible for defining position and size, not containing it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add a sentence specifying how the word should be used. The question is far too broad at the moment. You might even get as inappropriate hypernyms as 'variable' that would also apply to cost, temperature, dietary requirements ... do you want a term that is geometry- (space and shape) specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **adjustable**?

> Able to be adjusted.

*This way the adjustable stool can be converted from table height to bar height very easily.*

[Lexico]

Comment: Hmm.  That sounds great. Thanks!